# How extracting date and next two values using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file that has multiple tables that look like this:

```
<tr><td class='date_rec'>2/27/2023</td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>0.03</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>0.43</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>143</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>7.4</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>49.1</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>35.8</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>41.2</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>93</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>65</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>84</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>36.9</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>7.1</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>170.2</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>44.5</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
```

What I'd like to do is find the date `class='date_rec'`, extract the date and then extract the `'data_rec_v'` value for only the next 2 lines.

In this case, the extracted values would be `'2/27/2023', '0.03', '0.43'`.  I've made many BS4 attempts without success.  Can anyone give me a hand?  Thanks in advance for any constructive suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ara various ways to get your goal - Assuming it is not the only row to extract you could use `list` or `dict` to store the values.

Following `dict comprehension` is selecting all rows with a `class="date_rec"`, extracts via `stripped_strings` alle texts that could be sliced to the first three:

```
[
    list(e.stripped_strings)[:3]
    for e in soup.select('tr:has(>td.date_rec)')
]
```

Or without storing values simply print:

```
for e in soup.select('tr:has(>td.date_rec)'):
    print(
        ','.join(
            list(e.stripped_strings)[:3]
        ) 
    )
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr><td class='date_rec'>2/27/2023</td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>0.03</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>0.43</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>143</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>7.4</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>49.1</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>35.8</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>41.2</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>93</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>65</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>84</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>36.9</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>7.1</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>170.2</td><td class='data_rec_f'> </td></tr></table></td>
<td class='date_rec'><table class='inside_table'><tr><td class='data_rec_v'>44.5</td><td class='data_rec_f'>Y</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[
    list(e.stripped_strings)[:3]
    for e in soup.select('tr:has(>td.date_rec)')
]
```

##### Output

```
[['2/27/2023', '0.03', '0.43']]
```

Comment: This does it...thanks!  I was making it way more difficult than I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method. To search for a find date, specify the 'td' tag and the 'date_rec' class, this will return you the first element found. A search for the 'data_rec_v' class, using find_all, will return to you all the elements with this class, then you can extract them by referring to the position in the list. Here is an example of the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


file = open('date.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "lxml")
data = soup.find('td', class_='date_rec')
data_v = soup.find_all('td', class_='data_rec_v')[:2]
print(f'date - {data.text}')
for d in data_v:
    print(f'data_v - {d.text}')
```

will return:

```
date - 2/27/2023
data_v - 0.03
data_v - 0.43
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty list to receive the values ​​of 'td' and also created a dictionary with a data property that is in the class 'class='date_rec', then I put everything in the same dictionary 'data'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

value = []
data = {}
with open('html.html', 'r') as fd:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fd, 'html.parser')
    soup.contents
    values = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'data_rec_v'})
    date = soup.find('td',{'class':'date_rec'})

    date = str(date.text)

    for i in values:
        finder_values = i.text
    
        value.append(finder_values)

    data[date] = value

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
```

dict:
{'2/27/2023': ['0.03', '0.43', '143', '7.4', '49.1', '35.8', '41.2', '93', '65', '84', '36.9', '7.1', '170.2', '44.5']}